# Retrieved data from firebase always null

Tags: java, firebase

I have data. I want to get data from Firebase. This is my structure:

```
"data" : {
   "A01" : {
     "status" : 1,
     "tglkeluar" : "12-03-2019"
    },
   "A02" : {
     "status" : 1,
     "tglkeluar" : "10-03-2019"
   }
 },
```

This is my structure:

[image: structure]

And I used this code to get data from child "A01" **only**:

```
mDatabaseA01 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data").child("A01");
mDatabaseA01.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Data status = postSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
            Toast.makeText(HalamanAdmin.this, status.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

But the data is null. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Can you post the `Data` class ?

Comment: I think you go one level too far. There is no need for a loop. Just do `Data status = dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);`

Comment: lemme know if it did help. consider accepting the answer if it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    Data status = postSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
    Toast.makeText(HalamanAdmin.this, status.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Your data no longer exists with children objects since you are inside the children.
Instead, you should do this

```
Data status = new Data(dataSnapshot.get("status"), dataSnapshot.get("tglkeluar");
```

Please remember to have the constructor on the Data class

```
public Data(String status, String tglkeluar){
    this.status = status;
    this.tglkeluar = tglkeluar;
}
```

Comment: but i want the ONLY data from 'A01'..if i used this code. data from 'A02' will be read too

Comment: this will only get data from 'A01', do not change your reference. just replace the code i mentioned @WildanRomiza